# Creating new column in data frame with condition on nonempty cells

Tags: r, if-statement, dataframe, is-empty

I have a table looking like this:

```
  A   B
  aa  bb
  aa  
  aa  bb
```

And I want to Check if a data frame cell is blank and if yes find a result table like this:

```
  A  B  S
  aa bb bb
  aa    aa
  aa bb bb
```

I'm using this code but it doesn't work

```
for(k in dim(df))
  if (df$BB == ""){
    df$S <- df$AA
  }else {df$S <- df$BB}
```

Comment: Have a look at `ifelse()`

Comment: my problem is testing character 0 cell!!

Comment: Please use `dput(df)` to show your data. Put the result of `dput(df)` in your question, i.e. edit your question: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48989530/edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'ifelse' is your friend here. It's vectorized so no need for a loop here.

```
df <- data.frame(A = c("aa","aa","aa"), B = c("bb","","bb"))
df$S <- ifelse(df$B == '', df$A, df$B) 

#   A  B  S
#1 aa bb bb
#2 aa    aa
#3 aa bb bb
```

If you wanted to adjust your code, this works, but it's less efficient then the `ifelse` variant:

```
df$S = NA
for(k in 1:nrow(df)) df$S[k] <- if (df$B[k] == "") df$A[k] else df$B[k]
```

Note the `1:nrow(df)` instead of `dim(df)` and fixed indexing (`df$B[k]` vs `df$BB`)

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems with your loop: (1) you are looping over `dim(df)`, which is the vector `[3, 2]`, and (2) you don't actually index off of `k` within the loop. You could fix the code you have now like this:

```
df = data.frame(
  AA = c("aa", "aa", "aa"),
  BB = c("bb", "", "bb"),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)


for(k in 1:nrow(df)) {
  if (df$BB[k] == "") {
    df$S[k] <- df$AA[k]
  } else {
    df$S[k] <- df$BB[k]
  }
}
```

However, as others have pointed out, `ifelse` is more efficient, and it's a good function to get the hang of for lots of uses:

```
df$SS = ifelse(df$BB == "", df$AA, df$BB)
# > df
#   AA BB  S SS
# 1 aa bb bb bb
# 2 aa    aa aa
# 3 aa bb bb bb
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that on large data.frames and with a slow computer `ifelse()` is a bit slow sometimes. So in your case a simple workaround (since you are using strings) would be:

```
df$S <- df$B
df$S[df$B==""] <- df$A[df$B==""]
```

edited according to jogo's comment

Comment: Oh, yes, sorry. you are right of course